# Unable to access a file in a director using spyder (Python) in a virtualbox

Tags: python, virtualbox

Whenever I am trying to access a file using **os.system('cmd /k "flarestrings C:\Users\Windows 10\Downloads\Malwares\Virus\1" | rank_strings --scores>C:\Users\Windows 10\Downloads\Malwares\Results\output1.txt"')** in a Virtualbox (Windows 10) using spyder, it is giving me the error : "**255
Access is denied.**". For more details, please click the link to see the figure.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b_dHwvp79iWgBAYApFJ-JRbkIP7bOx72/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Open the Spyder in administrator mode. This will solve your problem...